# to_html replacing <, > in daraframes with weird characters while converting it to html

Tags: python, html, pandas

I have a pandas data frame and there is a column which contains strings like these:

```
    Column B
    <a href="path_to_some_filea.txt" >value_of_a</a>
    <a href="path_to_some_fileb.txt" >value_of_b</a>
```

I converted the above pandas dataframe to html using to_html like this:

```
    df.to_html(index_names=False)
```

The converted html code replaces the <,> in the string with weird characters. The converted html for the specific column looks like this:

```
    &lt;a href="path_to_some_filea.txt" &gt;value_of_a&lt;/a&gt;
    &lt;a href="path_to_some_fileb.txt" &gt;value_of_b&lt;/a&gt;
```

Does anyone know why this is happening and how to fix this issue ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set escape argument in [`df.to_html`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_html.html) to `False`, to prevent special characters escaping:

```py
    df.to_html(index_names=False, escape=False)
```

It is set to `True` by default and it convert the characters <, >, and & to HTML-safe sequences.