# Newline character for pandas .to_html?

Tags: python, html, pandas, dataframe

I'm working on a script that needs to convert a dataframe to a html table. All is good so far, except for newline indicators are not recognised when i view the output.

E.g. the string `"Hello < br > World"` or `"Hello \n World"` will just output as shown, not with a newline.

Are there any workarounds or special keys that I'm unaware of for creating newlines within a pandas html table?

< br > includes the spaces since it creates an actual breakpoint on this page by the way.

Thank you :)

Comment: How are you viewing the output? This may just be how strings look - for instance, in debug output.

Comment: @topsail It is output into a html file - containing other html elements such as graphs using plotly. Viewing this html file via microsoft edge.

Comment: That doesn't explain much. Post the actual HTML source. A newline in HTML *is* `<br>`. I suspect Pandas HTML-encodes the text before it's emitted *as it should*. Imagine what would happen if a value contained `<`. Or `<script>window.alert('gotcha');<script>` if Pandas didn't encode the text

Comment: From the [to_html docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_html.html) `escape: bool, default True.
Convert the characters <, >, and & to HTML-safe sequences.`. If you're absolutely certain all text is safe, or if take care of escaping non-HTML text yourself, you can set `escape` to `False`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [to\_html replacing <, > in daraframes with weird characters while converting it to html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62610780/to-html-replacing-in-daraframes-with-weird-characters-while-converting-it-t)

Comment: `< br >` is exactly the same as `<br>` by the way. The extra space is ignored by browsers. You'll have to clean up the text and replace any newlines with `<br>` or better yet, wrap paragraphs with `<div></div>` or `<p></p>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply the changes that you want in the dataframe like this using `render` and `df.style.format`:

```py
import pandas as pd

data = {'Text': ["Hello <br> World", "Hello \n World"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

def add_line_breaks(text):
    return text.replace('\n', '<br>')

df_styled = df.style.format({'Text': add_line_breaks})

html_table = df_styled.render()

with open('output.html', 'w') as file:
    file.write(html_table)
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: There's nothing wrong with `<br>` in HTML 5 , it's a [void element](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#void-elements)  while `<br/>` [should be avoided](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#start-tags). Browsers convert it to `<br>` anyway. The reason your code works is that `render()` alone doesn't escape HTML. That's the same as passing `escape:False` to `to_html`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thanks for mentioning that, i edited my code

Comment: @OmidRoshani thank you! This helps big time, however, I like the formatting of the tables when using `to_html`, are there params to generate tables from `render`?

Comment: @Harry no problem, as i remember there is not

Comment: I tried to use this, but was told render didn't exist.  It asked if I meant _render, but then it wanted certain arguments if _render was called.  Bitrot already?